# Play on the Metal Mario level in Super Smash Bros. (N64)

Tags: super-smash-bros

Is it possible in multiplayer mode to play on the level that in single player you fight Metal Mario?

I ask because I do not like levels with environment distractions.

Comment: This question seemed to initially be about playing on the level Metal Mario is faced on, not playing as Metal Mario, the character.

Comment: It is, and was stated more clearly before the edits. It was quite clear before; please stop making **minor** syntactical changes as this goes against the community guidelines and has made the question ambiguous.

Comment: I'm not sure of the validity of this, so it isn't an answer, but an internet search you can unlock it with a Gameshark, by using code 800A4D09 000D

Comment: Prior to edits, it was specifically asking for a mod or a hack, which doesn't get a very good reception at Arqade.  It was modified to hopefully get an answer to the root question, which is the ability to play on the level you mentioned.  An answer can provide a mod or a hack as a solution to the problem, but does not restrict answers to those alone, as your original wording implied.

Comment: The competitive community tends to center on Dreamland and Hyrule and occasionally Congo as the standard stages.  Congo is the one with zero hazards, just moving platforms, and the barrel rarely makes any significant difference.  Dreamland is next best as the wind only affects you when standing on the ground on the half of the stage it is blowing towards.  Hyrule tornadoes are annoying but easy to avoid unless it is trying to edge guard you.

Comment: @fbueckert The Help Center states that it's alright to ask about "Game-specific hardware and utilities" ( http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ), and I think Game Shark counts as one despite also being a hack.

Comment: @jSepia And as I said, the original wording doesn't get a very good reception here.  By mentioning those specifically, any other solution is discarded.  I'm not saying it's off-topic; quite the contrary, I edited it so we could keep it, and hopefully still help the asker.  But our stance on straight up Game Shark/Game Genie/whatever hack or mod recommendations is to re-word them to expose the root problem.  If the question can't be re-worded to be acceptable, then we close it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can confirm [Sconibulus' comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/110594/play-on-the-metal-mario-level-in-super-smash-bros-n64#comment148670_110594) above. The Game Shark code **800A4D09 000D** allows you to play VS mode on the Metal Mario stage.

[image: Metal Mario Stage]

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the stage cannot be unlocked normally and is only playable using hacks or GameShark codes.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: There is one unlockable level in super smash bros. It is the Classic Mushroom Kingdom map and you unlock it by beating the singleplayer with all the original 8 fighters, this is how it looks:

```
P- Pipe with Pirahna Plant  
W- Pipe without Pirahna Plant  
/ - Weighted Platform  
@- Possible location of a POW block  

          @                           @  
          P               @                                   
***********    @       ////        *******  
             ******        ////      *******  
                                                P  
*********************            **********************  
                    * W          *  
                    *            *
```

Taken from [Nunya Business's guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/n64/198854-super-smash-bros/faqs/3589) on [Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/).

Comment: What Mushroom Kingdom has to do with the Metal Mario level is beyond me.

Comment: @jw013 Nothing. But googlers ending up here might be happy with the extra clarification. It doesn't hurt anybody.

Comment: Nowadays, information overload and not being able to find the relevant information quickly is a bigger problem than simply not having the information.  Copying information to irrelevant places is not helping the issue.  If you feel that the information you provided is useful, make a new question for it where your answer would be relevant.  The SE network does let you answer your own questions.

Comment: The only reason I haven't downvoted this answer is the "short answer: no" answers the question (sort of - there are rom hacks / cheat codes that might make it "possibly" instead of "no").  However, then you waste about 15-20 seconds of everyone's time when they read all the way through your long answer and realize it has *nothing* to do with the short answer or the question.